# How To Create Dynamic List View

Tags: java, android

I Want To Create Dynamic List View As I Clicked A button a Title text add To My List View in A Simple Note Android project I have Create Note Activity Witch contains A Save Button  Want To when Clicked Save Button At Main Note Activity List View Save My Title.

Comment: please check this website: [Link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: You might consider taking a look at this. https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create an XML layout first in your project's res/layout/main.xml folder:

```
**
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:text="Add New Item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addItems"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**

This is a simple layout with a button on the top and a list view on the bottom. Note that the ListView has the id @android:id/list which defines the default ListView a ListActivity can use.

```
public class ListViewDemo extends ListActivity {
//LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

//DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//RECORDING HOW MANY TIMES THE BUTTON HAS BEEN CLICKED
int clickCounter=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

//METHOD WHICH WILL HANDLE DYNAMIC INSERTION
public void addItems(View v) {
    listItems.add("Clicked : "+clickCounter++);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is the default list item layout supplied by Android, and you can use this stock layout for non-complex things.

listItems is a List which holds the data shown in the ListView. All the insertion and removal should be done on listItems; the changes in listItems should be reflected in the view. That's handled by ArrayAdapter adapter, which should be notified using:

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

An Adapter is instantiated with 3 parameters: the context, which could be your activity/listactivity; the layout of your individual list item; and lastly, the list, which is the actual data to be displayed in the list.